# UnauthorizedError while connecting node.js express API through Postman on Hyperledger fabric v1

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, express-jwt

I'm running the [Balance transfer example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer) of Hyperledger fabric ver 1 on Ubuntu server. Exposed port 4000 on Node.js and trying to test API with POSTMAN tool. For each request (POST or GET) I'm getting the same error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at middleware (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:76:21)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express-unless/index.js:47:5
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at urlencodedParser (/usr/src/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

My guess is that there is something needed to configure **jwt-express** library. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I was not passing the authorization header **JSON Web Token (JWT)** which is generated while user is registered in the network.

Comment: As I said above I forgot to pass authorization token which is required for each API request. So, there was no issue basically. REST API request samples can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/balance-transfer#sample-rest-apis-requests).

Comment: [Login](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/balance-transfer#login-request) Request is needed first to get the token. This token should be used for other requests. For example, the following key/value must be included in the header: '"authorization: Bearer <put JSON Web Token here>"'